# How to load a page *syncronous* in Javascript inside a Flutter Webview using location.href or other command

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, webview, dart

I would like to load a page:

```
window.location.href='http://www.g1.com.br';
```

or by using

```
window.location.assign('http://www.g1.com.br');
```

and then execute the next command against this page.

If I execute the code below in Browsers's console it will do the alert before the page is loaded:

```
window.location.href='http://www.g1.com.br'; 
alert('oi');
```

In dart lang, for example, if href were an asynchronous function that loads a page, I'd do:

```
href.load('http://www.g1.com').then(execJs(myJsVar));
```

What I'm trying to achieve is doing some web scrape using javascript in a WebView, that runs in Flutter. The manner I found to navigate between several pages without to deal with `onPageFinished` method of flutter's WebView is doing the navigation entirely in Javascript inside a WebView.

But I don't know too much of Javascript. `href` and `assign` appear to be asyncs functions, but I don't know how to apply some kind of `then` to it if it's
possible.

the real code:

I load a page and execute other commands on that page to fill a form.
Than I load the second page and do the same,

```
window.location.assign('%targetUrl%');

document.querySelectorAll('#email')
    .forEach(
        function (field, index, arr) {
            field.value = '%username%';
            field.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        }
    );

document.querySelectorAll('#pass')
    .forEach(
        function (field, index, arr) {
            field.value = '%password%';
            field.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        }
    );
window.location.assign('%targetUrl2%');

/// fill other forms, submit....
```

Comment: Not going to happen. New page wipes out script in current page. It's a whole new `window` instance

Comment: ok, I got it. so In my case, I should load the page externally and then execute the Js commands on it?

Comment: right but only if you can get code in other page